# Change bitmap colormapping c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, colormap

I have a float[,] matrix of values, with this code i've been able to convert the matrix into a Bitmap, which eventually is plotted on a pictureBox.

```
private unsafe Bitmap ToBitmap(float[,] rawImage)
    {
        int width = rawImage.GetLength(1);
        int height = rawImage.GetLength(0);

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = img.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
        );
        ColorARGB* startingPosition = (ColorARGB*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                double color = rawImage[i, j];

                byte rgb = (byte)(color * 255); // lowering this value make the image less saturated, but still grayscale

                ColorARGB* position = startingPosition + j + i * width;
                position->A = 255;
                position->R = rgb;
                position->G = rgb;
                position->B = rgb;
            }

        img.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        return img;

    }



public struct ColorARGB
    {
        public byte B;
        public byte G;
        public byte R;
        public byte A;

        public ColorARGB(Color color)
        {
            A = color.A;
            R = color.R;
            G = color.G;
            B = color.B;
        }

        public ColorARGB(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
        {
            A = a;
            R = r;
            G = g;
            B = b;
        }

        public Color ToColor()
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
        }
    }
```

with this code the result is a graylvl image, with some saturated parts; I want to remap the color into a "jet" colormap or "hot", but I don't know where i should start from.
The idea would be: 
All matrix values below a threshold and above a threshold should be mapped with a particular color (in the case of jet cMap they would be red and blue, while the values between the 2 limits are mapped to all the other values).

The code posted is adapted from what I was able to find online, how do I proceed? All i could find was a remap of colormap but to change an old color to a new one, not the whole ColorMapping.

Comment: Please dispose off the bitmap otherwise sooner or later you will run into memory leaks

Comment: done into an exitButton for now :)